# Modify the node title with the node ID before saving it

Tags: 8, hooks

I need to modify the node title while saving the node ID. I implemented `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` as follows.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()
 */
function module_name_form_form_id_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['title']['#access'] = FALSE;
  $form['#entity_builders'][] = 'change_node_title';   
}

function change_node_title($entity_type, NodeInterface $node, $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $node_id = $node->nid->value; // Not getting the node details
  $node->setTitle('Custom Title -' . $node_id);
}
```

The node details aren't found from the #entity_builders callback.

How can modify the node title before saving it? I don't want to use any custom modules for this. I don't want to use `hook_node_presave()` either, as it would affect the cloned nodes.

Comment: Using same code which is working fine for me. Is there any changes in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never tried **entity_buildres** but you could probably use the old and tried way of adding a submit handler

```
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
  // this is the create form id, edit form would be node_article_edit_form
  if($form_id == 'node_article_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'MODULENAME_change_title';
  }   
}

function MODULENAME_change_title($form, $form_state) {
  $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  $node->setTitle('Custom Title - ' . $node->id());
  $node->save();
}
```

Comment: Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\\Core\\Entity\\EntityStorageException: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null:

Comment: The code is working on my setup just did some word changes from my setup, can you try on a clean install ?

Comment: Even it's working for me also with just small change as $node->id => $node->id(). @RubberDuckIsKing check with new Drupal installation or any other content type.

Comment: Yes its working now ! seems buggy sometimes

Comment: @AAjayReddy corrected the typo

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to use hook_entity_presave() for this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave().
 */
function MYMODULE_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  // save a different value as title
  if ($entity->bundle() == 'NODE_TYPE') {
    $entity->title = 'Custom Title - ' . $entity->id();
  }
}
```

Comment: We don't have node ID for the new nodes, it will work only for updated nodes