# How do I change the node title when saving it?

Tags: nodes, 9

For a content type (*Article*), when I create a new node and save it, I want to append a field value (for example, *Location*) to the node title.

There seems to be great answers using custom plugins ([Modify the node title with the node ID before saving it](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258057/modify-node-title-with-node-id-before-saving)) and even modules ([How do I build the node title from field values when saving the node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/266351/how-to-build-node-title-from-field-values-on-node-save)), but they're not applicable to Drupal 9.

If the suggested solution requires creating custom module and overriding a function, then please direct me to some implementation guide and specify files locations as I'm a newbie in writing Drupal code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this without writing code, the module you want for Drupal 9 is [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel).  Nodes are entities, so you can use this to set the label (title).

Comment: I will give a try right now, does it provide ability to insert the modified title while saving the node? Or it will update the node after being saved?

Comment: @Cortex It generates the node title based on the pattern that you give it when the node is saved for the first time.  There's no need to re-save the node.

Comment: Great! I will respond to the answer once I give it a try

Comment: Worked as expected! Also Pathauto was able to pick the title and use it to generate my custom pattern without issues, I verified the title value in the Database.

Comment: I'd just like to add the I had to add a new text field (Article Title) to use its token in the replacement along with 'Location'. Title field will be hidden and the token `[node:title]` will not work.
You can update all previous nodes by ticking the option: Re-save in from 'Automatic Label' tab.